# append data to an existing csv file with data

Tags: powershell

Below is the data i already have in my csv

```
ServerName  Start Time  End Time
localhost   1599222660  1599222660
```

now i have below data which needs to be added in this existing data

```
pl_AVERAGE  pl_MAX  pl_MIN  rta_AVERAGE rta_MAX     rta_MIN
0           0       0       0.044726667 0.044726667 0.044726667
```

i tried like below but getting error

```
Export-Csv "C:\Script\sum.csv" -NoType -Append
```

```
Export-Csv : Cannot append CSV content to the following file: C:\Script\sum.csv. The appended object does not have a property that corresponds to the following column: 
ServerName. To continue with mismatched properties, add the -Force parameter, and then retry the command.
At C:\script\Capacity_Data.ps1:528 char:41
+ ... pscustomobject]$Hash | Export-Csv "C:\Script\sum.csv" -NoType -Append
+                            ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (ServerName:String) [Export-Csv], InvalidOperationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CannotAppendCsvWithMismatchedPropertyNames,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.ExportCsvCommand
```

i tried adding **-force**, but then it was not writing anything to the csv

below is the code

```
$csvContents = @()
            $row = New-Object System.Object 
            $row | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "ServerName" -Value $Server
            $row | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Start Time" -Value $FirstTimeStamp
            $row | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "End Time" -Value $FirstTimeStamp
            $csvContents += $row
#writing first 3 columns
            $csvContents | Export-CSV -Path "C:\Script\sum.csv" -NoTypeInformation -Append
    
            $New_Extracted_Data | Export-Csv "C:\Script\Final.csv" -NoType
            $New_Extracted_Data | Select-Object -Property * -ExcludeProperty timestamp |
            Export-Csv "C:\Script\Final.csv" -NoType
            $Properties = ($New_Extracted_Data[0] | Get-Member -MemberType NoteProperty |
            Where Name -ne 'timestamp').Name
            $Hash = [ordered]@{}
                foreach ($Property in $Properties) {
                    $Hash[$Property] = (($New_Extracted_Data.$Property | Measure -Sum).Sum)/$NumberOfRowsToPick

                }
#2nd time writing 
                [pscustomobject]$Hash | Export-Csv "C:\Script\sum.csv" -NoType -Append
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to add properties to each row, you can use a `foreach` loop to iterate the data rows and add the members:

```
$csv = Import-Csv -Path 'c:\script\sum.csv'
foreach ($row in $csv) {
    $row | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "ServerName" -Value $Server
    $row | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "Start Time" -Value $FirstTimeStamp
    $row | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -Name "End Time" -Value $FirstTimeStamp
}
$csv | Export-Csv -Path 'c:\script\sum.csv' -NoType
```

Since `$row` is a reference to an item in the `$csv` collection, any change made to `$row` will automatically be reflected in `$csv`.

If you expect those added property values to be different for each row, you will need to add the logic within the loop to do so.

Comment: i tried using foreach loop and append in case of multiple servers but it is not appending the values. any idea what is wrong.

Comment: If you have a single object (as opposed to an array of objects) with a set of properties, you will be able to use `add-member` to add a property to that object. In the case of multiple servers, how do you know which server goes with the other data?

Answer (score 0):

Another take on [AdminOfThings good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63744511/4749264), you don't need to loop if you use `Select-Object` to add the properties, which might look something like this:

```
Import-Csv -Path 'c:\script\sum.csv' |
Select-Object *,
    @{ Name = 'ServerName'; Expression = { $Server } }
    @{ Name = 'Start Time"'; Expression = { $FirstTimeStamp } }
    @{ Name = 'End Time'; Expression = { $FirstTimeStamp } } |
Export-Csv -Path 'c:\script\sum.csv' -NoTypeInformation
```

Personally I hardly ever use `Add-Member` for this sort of thing.  The only advantage I'm aware of is preserving some of the type data, However, in this case you'd already be dealing with PSCustomObjects...

Also, I think an important part of your initial problem is the use of the `-Append` parameter.  It essentially means append new records not append to existing records.  If you look at both solutions here we're overwriting or creating a new CSV file.

The key is to have the objects in whole before exporting the new CSV file.